# ngrok error Failed to read valid http request: malformed HTTP request

Tags: linux, tunnel, ngrok

I'm using ngrok building a Secure tunnels to localhost server

On server side I run the command start ngrok

```
./bin/ngrokd -domain="tunnel.kmic168.com" -httpAddr=":8080"
```

Display

```
[07/12/17 17:37:16] [INFO] [registry] [tun] No affinity cache specified
[07/12/17 17:37:16] [INFO] [metrics] Reporting every 30 seconds
[07/12/17 17:37:16] [INFO] Listening for public http connections on [::]:8080
[07/12/17 17:37:16] [INFO] Listening for public https connections on [::]:443
[07/12/17 17:37:16] [INFO] Listening for control and proxy connections on [::]:4443
```

It seems fine. Then I run the command on client side

```
./ngrok -subdomain=rbp -config="ngrok.cfg" 80
```

and the

```
Tunnel Status: reconnecting .
```

Alway reconnecting. Then I checkd the server side display these error

> [07/12/17 17:40:13] [INFO] [pub:7ac836d4] New connection from
>   119.130.171.143:25904 [07/12/17 17:40:13] [WARN] [pub:7ac836d4] Failed to read valid http request: malformed HTTP request
>   "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x9a\x01\x00\x00\x96\x03\x03;Qߓ\xccj\xb7nm\xa0\xe0\x86\x04\u007fH{W5\x10\xb1\xc4\xcc\xed\xe5\xbf\xc9\x00\xa1ĥbq\x00\x00\x1c\xc0/\xc0+\xc00\xc0,\xc0\x13\xc0\t\xc0\x14\xc0"
>   [07/12/17 17:40:13] [DEBG] [pub:7ac836d4] Closing [07/12/17 17:40:23]
>   [INFO] [metrics] Reporting:
>   {"bytesIn.count":0,"bytesOut.count":0,"connMeter.count":0,"connMeter.m1":0,"httpTunnelMeter.count":0,"linux":0,"osx":0,"other":0,"tcpTunnelMeter.count":0,"tunnelMeter.count":0,"tunnelMeter.m1":0,"windows":0}

Here is my cfg file content

```
server_addr: "tunnel.kmic168.com:8080"
trust_host_root_certs: false
```

Is there a solution to resolve this error? Thank you very much!

Comment: I did test  nc -v -w 10 -z tunnel.kmic168.com 8080
Connection to tunnel.kmic168.com 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!  everything goes fine. but still Failed to read valid http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I found the solution

https://gist.github.com/lyoshenka/002b7fbd801d0fd21f2f

you have to use the port 4443

Comment: Thank you for sharing this useful link.